# c# Unity 5.11.10 dependency injection StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have just upgraded Unity package to latest version and I am getting a possible circular dependency 'Stackoverflow' exception when I am registering 2 of my dto object mappers.

UnityConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterTypes()
{
        ...
        Container.RegisterType<IResultMapper<Object1>, Object1DtoObject1Mapper>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMethod(nameof(IBaseMapper.Init)));
        Container.RegisterType<IResultMapper<Object2>, Object2DtoObject2Mapper>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMethod(nameof(IBaseMapper.Init)));
}
```

Object2DtoObject2Mapper.cs

```
public class Object2DtoObject2Mapper: ResultMapperConfigurator<Object2Dto, Object2>
{
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the mapping configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        Property(dto => dto.Id, entity => entity.Id);
        

        Collection(dto => dto.property, entity => entity.property, Object1Mapper);
        

        Validate();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    #region Mappers

    //error occurs here
    [Dependency]
    public Object1DtoObject1Mapper Object1Mapper { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Object1DtoObject1Mapper.cs

```
public class Object1DtoObject1Mapper: ResultMapperConfigurator<Object1Dto, Object1>
{
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the mapping configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        Property(dto => dto.Id, entity => entity.Id);
        

        Collection(dto => dto.property, entity => entity.property, Object2Mapper);
        

        Validate();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    #region Mappers

    //error occurs here
    [Dependency]
    public Object2DtoObject2Mapper Object2Mapper { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

In each dto object mapper there are dependencies of the another used to map the appropriate properties or collections. The above code produced no errors using the previous version of Unity (4.0.1). Could anyone tell me how to inject 'Object1DtoObject1Mapper' and 'Object2DtoObject2Mapper' in each mapper?

Comment: Why do you have or want a circular dependency via `Object1DtoObject1Mapper.Object2Mapper` and `Object2DtoObject2Mapper.Object1Mapper`?

Comment: Because the dto objects contains such properties. This is how the application is built and unfortunately cannot be changed.

Comment: Hi, you cant change Object1DtoObject1Mapper and Object2DtoObject2Mapper class content? What about usage of Lazy<T>? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @VitezslavSimon I can change it. What do you propose? The only thing I cannot change is the contents of Object1Dto and Object2Dto classes.

Comment: Init should not be called directly after instantiation or using others mapper data directly.

Perhaps this can lead you on desire way:
http://unitycontainer.org/tutorials/resolution/deferred.html